# How to set up a simple spring form at startup

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I am new to spring and learning a basic hello world application.Here is the doubt i came across. How to make the initial load page to index.jsp.I have my index.jsp in the WebContent folder.But each time i run the index.jsp from my eclipse to see the page.

```
http://localhost:8080/TestingSpring/index.jsp
```

However when i run the project it is going to

```
http://localhost:8080/TestingSpring/
```

and giving 404.Each time i have to run explicitly the index.jsp in my project to get the view.

Also my second doubt is in my index.jsp i have used an 
     Say Hello

and my controller class contains

```
@RequestMapping("/contacts")
public ModelAndView showContacts() {

    return new ModelAndView("contacts", "command", new Contact());
}
```

From the redirect it is loading the contact.jsp with spring form,Here is my contact.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>


 <title>Contact Manager</title>

<h2>Contact Manager</h2>
<form:form method="post" action="addContact.html">
<br>
<table>
<tbody><tr>
    <td><form:label path="firstname">First Name</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="firstname"></form:input></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="lastname">Last Name</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="lastname"></form:input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="lastname">Email</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="email"></form:input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="lastname">Telephone</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="telephone"></form:input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Contact">
    </td>
</tr>
```

How will i load this page directly without any redirect.Now from index.jsp      -->  contact.jsp it is going to display te spring form.How to do it directly.
How can i directly incude spring forms in my index.jsp.

Sharing the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
 <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name> 
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: @DilipKumar shared the web.xml

Answer (score 2):

Change your RequestMapping according to your Dispatcher Servlet Url Mapping.

In your case your Dispatcher Servlet URL pattern is *.html.. So Change your RequestMapping like this....

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contacts.html")
public ModelAndView showContacts() { }
```

Answer (score 1):

1)try changing the url to http://localhost:8080/TestingSpring/contacts/contacts.jsp

in your web.xml you change index.jsp to what ever jsp you want like shown below since you wanted contacts .jsp i have used that only

```
 <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>contacts.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
```

change to what ever jsp page you want.

Also change your servelet mapping to

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: but my  http://localhost:8080/TestingSpring/  is not giving me index.jsp it is still giving 404.Only when i explicitly run index.jsp it is loading

Comment: Also i am not able to add spring forms in the index.jsp unless it is redirected.What am i doing wrong here

Comment: its because in your web.xml you have given your servelet mapping wrong change it to as shown in answer

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /TestingSpring/contacts/contacts.jsp is what i am getting

Comment: no success. I am not having any applicationContext defined is it a problem?

Comment: what is the name of your servelet

Comment: I have solved this by adding  this in the controller
    @RequestMapping("/")
     public ModelAndView initial() {
          System.out.println("coming inside controller");
         return new ModelAndView("index", "command", new Complaint());
     }

So that it redirects to that page. But when is the <welcome-file-list>coming into play?

Answer (score 1):

Close the <form:form> tag in contacts.jsp and specify contacts.jsp in <welcome-file> of web.xml